# Block message from a Member as Another member in quickBlox WEB API

Tags: quickblox

I'm implementing quickBlox chat using WEBAPI. Is it possible to add members programmatically and create new group and member of the chat room that can block any member of chat room? Using webSDK only.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet. Now WebSDK doesn't support a wrraper around XMPP API, so you should include additional XMPP JS library for that.

Strophe.js (http://strophe.im/strophejs/)

and its Strophe.muc plugin (https://github.com/QuickBlox/sample-chat-xmpp-web/blob/master/js/libs/strophe.muc.js).